# Combining Jade Mixin output with the preceding tag in a template

Tags: pug

say my jade template looks something like this:

```
mixin foo(bar)
 .fizzle=bar

#baz.mixin foo('beef') //this isn't the right way
```

I'd like the resultant output to be:

```
<div id='baz' class='fizzle'>beef</div>
```

What is the proper way to combine the output of the mixin with the current tag?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you cannot do like that. Or you can try like follows:

```
mixin foo(bar)
 #baz.fizzle= bar

mixin foo('beef')
```

or

```
mixin foo(bar)
  | #{bar}

#baz.fizzle
  mixin foo('beef')
```